# Send request to website for crawl every second

Tags: python, time, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

i want to crawl a website every seconds for 4 hours, how can i do this.
my code is below.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

site = requests.get("http://example.com") 
soup =BeautifulSoup(site.text,'html.parser')
r = str(soup).split(",")
update_time = r[0]
price1 = r[2]
price2 = r[3]
print(update_time,price1,price2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` and `threading` module

```
import requests 
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def scrape():
    site = requests.get("http://example.com") 
    soup =BeautifulSoup(site.text,'html.parser')
    r = str(soup).split(",")
    update_time = r[0]
    price1 = r[2]
    price2 = r[3]
    print(update_time,price1,price2)

for i in range(14400):
    t = Thread(target=scrape)
    t.start()
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a schedule  module for this.

```
import schedule
import time
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def crawl():
    site = requests.get("http://example.com") 
    soup =BeautifulSoup(site.text,'html.parser')
    r = str(soup).split(",")
    update_time = r[0]
    price1 = r[2]
    price2 = r[3]
    print(update_time,price1,price2)

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(crawl)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

the four hours window can be achieved via crontab or with for loop.

You have to install the schedule module to run the above script

```
sudo pip install schedule
```